# Using Page_Load method in button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I trying to call `Page_Load` method after clicking `btnSubmit`. For my `Page_Load` I did databinding on dropdownlist box where column `caseprogress != 'ongoing'`. Then for my `btnSubmit_Click` I insert some data into another table, update `caseprogress = 'completed'` and also call of `Page_Load` method. But my dropdownlist box don't seem to be rebinding. (Unless I refresh the page) I try this method on other page it work but not for this. FYI I don't have any update panel in the page of this. Same go for the other one which is working.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //Bind data to Dropdownlist box
    }
}

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Insert / Update data of sql data table

   Page_Load(null, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Comment: why don't you just use post back by reloading that page again?

Comment: U mean Response.Redirect back to the page? I don't Response.Redirect cause I have a message display after button clicked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can have method to Bind the Dropdownlist

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindData();
    }
}

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Insert / Update data of sql data table

   BindData();
}

private void BindData()
{
    String policeid = (String)Session["policeid"];
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = MajorProject; Integrated Security= SSPI");
    con.Open();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select mr.memberreportid From PoliceAccount pa, MemberReport mr Where pa.policeid = '" + policeid + "' And pa.handle = mr.memberreportid And mr.caseprogress = 'ongoing'", con);
    da.Fill(ds);
    ddlMemberReportID.DataSource = ds;
    ddlMemberReportID.DataTextField = "memberreportid";
    ddlMemberReportID.DataValueField = "memberreportid";
    ddlMemberReportID.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
```

and remove `Page_Load(null, EventArgs.Empty);` code line

Comment: This is the best solution, add your code to another function and then just call that whenever needed.

Comment: I try rebind data at `btnSubmit_Click` it still don't refresh the dropdownlist box.

Comment: added a text file download link on question

Answer (score 1):

your problem is probably your call to `Page_Load(null, EventArgs.Empty);`
It will cause a double call to Page_Load, the last one, which you call inside the `btn_Click`event, will have `IsPostback = true` and your data will not be bound.